# Is it possible to query the status of a service application using the client object model?

Tags: 2013, client-object-model, service-application

My goal is to query the statuses of services and service applications from a remote machine. I don't want to actually interact with the services, all I need is the "Started"/"Stopped" status you get in the Central Administration via "Application Management" -> "Manage service applications"/"Manage services on server".

Is this possible using the .NET Client Object Model of Sharepoint 2013? If yes, how? If not, why?